# momentjs time display locale

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I thought it was simple to display my local time in 24-hour notation in Javascript: `time: moment().format('LT');`

This is from the documentation, but returned is: `"11:52 PM"`, instead of what I expected: `"23:52"`

I also set `<html lang="nl">` in HTML, doesn't help either.
What is wrong? What must I do to get locale time displayed?

Edit: I checked package.json: moment version 2.24.0 is installed as dependency!
Edit 2: I also installed the `script src="moment-with-locales.js"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking over their documentation, Localized formats don't seem to support 24-hour time.

Use

```
moment().format('HH')
```

for 24-hour time.

Comment: Yes `HH:mm` is the correct format string I was looking for. But I must say that the documentation is not very clear, IMHO.